# Lumen / Laravel: Can't figure out how unittesting a json response works

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, lumen

I can't figure out how unit testing works.

I have controller which returns a JSON response

**Controller.php**

```
public function getDiscount(Request $request)
{
    if (isset($request) && !empty($request)) {
        return response()->json($this->discount->calculateDiscount($request->json()->all()))->getOriginalContent();
    }
}
```

With postman, this is the result of this route:

**Post by client:**

```
{
  "customer-id": "3",
  "items": [
    {
      "product-id": "A101",
      "quantity": "2",
      "unit-price": "9.75",
      "total": "19.50"
    },
    {
      "product-id": "A102",
      "quantity": "1",
      "unit-price": "49.50",
      "total": "49.50"
    }
  ],
  "total": "69.00"
}
```

**Response by API**

```
{
    "applied_discounts": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Tools Discount",
            "description": "Seems like you really like Tools, here's one for free!"
        }
    ],
    "discounted_items": [
        {
            "product-id": "A101",
            "quantity": "2",
            "unit-price": "9.75",
            "total": "19.50",
            "discounted_price": 15.6
        }
    ],
    "discounted_price": 65.1,
    "original_price": "69.00"
}
```

Now when I try to make unit test, this is what I came up with:

```
public function testToolsDiscount()
{
    $this->json('POST', '/discount',
        [
            'customer-id' => '3',
            'items' => [
                [
                    'product-id' => 'A101',
                    'quantity' => '2',
                    'unit-price' => '9.75',
                    'total' => '19.50'
                ],
                [
                'product-id' => 'A102',
                'quantity' => '1',
                'unit-price' => '49.50',
                'total' => '49.50'
                ]
            ],
            'total' => '69.00'
        ])
        ->seeJson(
            [
            'applied_discounts' => [
                [
                    'id' => 3,
                ]
            ],
        ]);
}
```

However when I run it, this is the error I get

> DiscountTest::testToolsDiscount Invalid JSON was returned from the
>   route. Perhaps an exception was thrown?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any middleware defined?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Nope

Comment: When running the test, can you do a `dd(response()->json($this->discount->calculateDiscount($request->json()->all()))->getOriginalContent());` before the `return` inside `getDiscount` function?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte hmm, nothing changed in my test, still the same output. However I just noticed this `Element 'phpunit', attribute 'syntaxCheck': The attribute 'syntaxCheck' is not allowed.` not sure if it has anything to do with the test itself

Comment: Can you show us where you define the route?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Well, that was it! I had a prefix befor the route, I can't believe that was it! Finally now I'm getting errors that I can make sense of! `Unable to find JSON fragment ["applied_discounts":[{"id":3}]] within [{"applied_discounts":[{"description":"...`

Comment: No problem, anytime. I've wrote an answer to help people with the same issue. You can send edit suggests if you think they are relevants.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Well it seems like mytest syntax is still wrong, so the route wasn't the only problem. My test is looking for `["applied_discounts":[{"id":3}]]` while my result is `[{"applied_discounts":[{"id":3}]}]`. But I'm not sure why my test isn't looking for an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your route matches the specified `'/discount'` with any prefix it may have.

Answer (score 0):

Define the proper route,

I recommend using [action()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-action) Helper function to add url, the main benefits of this function is when you change some text or prefix in route, 
Let say you change from `/discount` to `/discounts` in these case you don't need to change the route everywhere.

```
action('ControllerName@actionName');
```

Answer (score -1):

It's possible your post-body needs to be an actual JSON string, rather than an associative array.  It's also possible that the `json()` method requires a fully-qualified URL instead of a relative path.  If either is the case, this solution may not actually expose the problem, you'll just have to try them and see.  Otherwise, try this, it should at least offer some clues as to what's going wrong.  Add the following to your unit-test class and `dd()` the results.

```
/**
 * @param string $uri
 * @param string $method
 * @param array $body
 * @param array $headers
 * @param array $files
 * @param array $cookies
 * @return array
 */
public function callRoute(
    $uri,
    $method = 'GET',
    array $body = [],
    array $headers = [],
    array $files = [],
    array $cookies = []
) {
    foreach ($cookies as $name => $cookie) {
        $this->app->resolving(\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class, function (\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies $cookie) use ($name) {
            $cookie->disableFor($name);
        });
    }

    $uri = trim($uri, '/');
    $uriParts = parse_url($uri);
    //This value may be based on the APP_URL value in your .env, I'm not really sure.
    $root = !array_get($uriParts, 'host') ? trim(app(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class)->root(), '/').'/' : '';
    $uri = "$root$uri";
    $server = $this->transformHeadersToServerVars($headers);
    $response = $this->call($method, $uri, $body, $cookies, $files, $server);

    $headers = $response->headers->all();
    $code = $response->getStatusCode();
    $json = $content = $response->getContent();
    $json = json_decode($json, true);
    $content = ($json && json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE) ? $json : $content;

    return compact('code', 'headers', 'content');
}
```

I'd be willing to bet the following will expose an error message and stack trace.  You'll likely have to follow it up with some other `dd()` statements in your target controller, or wherever else your logic lives after that error points you in the right direction:

```
$body = [
    'customer-id' => '3',
    'items' => [
        [
            'product-id' => 'A101',
            'quantity' => '2',
            'unit-price' => '9.75',
            'total' => '19.50'
        ],
        [
            'product-id' => 'A102',
            'quantity' => '1',
            'unit-price' => '49.50',
            'total' => '49.50'
        ]
    ],
    'total' => '69.00'
];

$response = $this->callRoute('POST', '/discount', $body)['content'];
dd($response);
```

Comment: Not guessing the correct solution is not the same as providing a bad answer.  Based on the accepted answer, I can say that had you followed my instructions, you would have noticed the `code` part of the parse test response would have displayed `404`, a tipoff that the URI was wrong.  I'm not bothered you didn't opt for my answer, but could you please explain the down-vote.